# How to filter duplicate values in magento array?

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter, array

I am trying to get attribute option values for specific products.

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $baseUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $product1 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $op_array = array();
        $val_array = array();
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product1->getId());
        $_childProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        foreach ($_childProducts as $simpleProduct){

            // echo '<pre>' , var_dump($simpleProduct->getData()) , '</pre>';
            $sku = $simpleProduct->getSku();
           // echo "<br/>";
            $stringSku = '"' . $sku . '"';
            $sql = "select * from inventory_stock_4 where sku =". $stringSku;
            $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
            //var_dump($result);
            //echo $option_label = $result[0]['quantity'];
            //echo "<br/>";
            $tableName = $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');


            $sql2 = "select distinct * FROM " . $tableName . " where option_id=".$simpleProduct['jasani_size'];
            $result2 = $connection->fetchAll($sql2);
            $option_label = $result2[0]['value'];
            foreach($result2 as $size){

               var_dump($size);
    }
```

I get an array like this

```
         array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "611" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["value"]=> string(2) "XS" }
         array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "612"
     ["option_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
["value"]=> string(2) "XS" } 
        array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "613" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
["value"]=> string(2) "XS" }
         array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "614" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "25" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "4"
 ["value"]=> string(2) "XS" }
         array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "619" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "1"
 ["value"]=> string(1) "M" } 
        array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "620" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
["value"]=> string(1) "M" } 
        array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "621" 
    ["option_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
["value"]=> string(1) "M" }
         array(4) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "622"
     ["option_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["store_id"]=> string(1) "4"
 ["value"]=> string(1) "M" }
```

I get this repeated values like `XS` and `M` I can't filter unique vales in this.
I also tried `array_unique()`, `array_filter()` nut no use.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are trying to do that way, but if you set `$option_label = []` before the first foreach and replace `$option_label = $result2[0]['value'];` with `$option_label[$result2[0]['value']] = $result2[0]['value'];` you will have an array of unique labels.

Comment: looks like you should filter with the store_id

Comment: Use in_array to remove duplicates inside foreach..

Answer (score 1):

array_unique is not working on multi-dimensionnal array, see the doc [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#refsect1-function.array-unique-notes) :

> `array_unique()` is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

To filter an multi-dimensionnal try :

```
$temp = array_unique(array_column($array, 'value'));
$unique_arr = array_intersect_key($array, $temp);
```